# Bash script to display directory listing gives error

Tags: bash, shell-script

I wrote a simple bash script (I'm pretty new to it, you know!) to accept a directory as its argument and print its listing, testing for files and directories. Here's how I approached it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Lists all files and directories (non-recursively) in a specified directory

if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "Error. Please specify only one directory. ($#)"
    exit
fi

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "No directory specified. Exiting."
    exit
fi

echo "Listing for $1:"

$dirs=`ls $1`
echo "Dirs: $dirs" # Just to confirm if all is well

# Loop through and print
for i in $dirs;
do
    if [ -f $i ]; then
        echo "File: $i"
    elif [ -d $i ]; then
        echo "Directory: $i"
    fi
done
```

The problem is in my for loop. When I run this script and feed it my home directory, I get this error:

`./list_files_and_dirs.sh: line 16: =Calibre: command not found`

I know I'm making a mistake in command substitution involving variables, but I just don't know what. Someone please help!

================= Update =================

Here's the new (final section) code as per inputs from answers:

```
dirs=`ls "$1"`
#echo "Dirs: $dirs" # Just to confirm if all is well

IFS=$'\n'

# Loop through and print
for i in $dirs;
do
    if [ -f "$i" ]; then
        echo "File: $i"
    elif [ -d "$i" ]; then
        echo "Directory: $i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: You might want to add `else echo "Other: $i"` to handle things that aren't files or directories.  (Or do you *want* to just ignore them?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note: I've assumed you're teaching yourself Bash. Do not use this code in production. `find "$directory" -maxdepth 1 -type d` will get you the directories, `-type f` will get you the files.**

Since it is complaining about line 16, let's have a look at it:

```
$dirs=`ls $1`
```

If you want to assign to a variable, you should not include the `$`. I'm guessing you meant:

```
dirs=`ls $1`
```

What's happening now, is this:

- `$dirs` is probably empty, so substituted with nothing.
- The `ls` command is run, and its output substituted in the 'command'.
- The first file in your directory is called `Calibre`, leaving you with the command: `=Calibre x y z ...`
- `=Calibre` is not a valid command, thus the error.

However, we're not there yet: this will go wrong if there are spaces in any of the filenames. To fix that, you need to do more:

- You need to include `IFS=$'\n'` somewhere before the `for` loop. This sets the fields separator to the linefeed character, which stops the `for` loop from splitting up the files on the spaces or tabs (it's technically possible for a file to have a linefeed in its filename as well: you're unlikely to ever encounter such a file and it won't cause serious problems in this case if you do run into such a file, but it's worth being aware of the possibility in case it ever does matter).
- In order for a filename with spaces not to turn into several different arguments to `-f` and `-d`, you need to put quotes `$i`. (So: `[ -f "$i" ]` and `[ -d "$i" ]`. In order to support directories with spaces in them, you should do the same for `$1` where it is used.

Comment: I put double quotes everywhere and set `IFS=''` before the for loop. Now my `for` loop prints nothing, though a simple `echo "$i"` shows the listing. Any idea what's wrong? Should I update the code in question or should I post a new question?

Comment: @dotslash: My mistake. It should be `IFS=$'\n'`. I've fixed it in the answer as well.

Comment: I did it but still no output. Please see the updated code in question. All I get is `Listing for /home/ankush:` and then nothing.

Comment: @dotslash: Don't quote `$dirs` in the for loop. In that case, you actually *do* want it to turn into separate arguments, because you want to consider each part separately.

Comment: Did that but still nothing. :( Mind running this on your system, please? :-)

Comment: Add a `cd "$1"` in there. `ls` only gives you the filenames without the path, so it's looking for the files in the current directory instead of the one you passed in.

Comment: Works now, thanks! Just one thing I'd like to add: I removed `IFS=$'\n'` and it's still working. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Yeah, it works now, but try creating a file with a space in its name (`cp /dev/null "foo bar"`).

Answer (score 5):

Marinus already explained why you were getting that error. I would like to point out that there's no need for `ls` here. That way, you avoid all the problems that come with [parsing its output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You could just do:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Lists all files and directories (non-recursively) in a specified directory

if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "Error. Please specify only one directory. ($#)"
    exit
fi

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "No directory specified. Exiting."
    exit
fi

echo "Listing for $1:"

# Loop through and print
for i in "$1"/*;
do
    if [ -f "$i" ]; then
        echo "File: $i"
    elif [ -d "$i" ]; then
        echo "Directory: $i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I'll be damned! What a neat trick! O.O

Comment: @G-Man lol, I should indeed. Thanks :)